Very High gas fee in my staking contract
I am trying to implement my staking contract, for some reason calling stake() or claimRewards()
costs 2MATIC ~ 4MATIC.
I know my code is kind of complex since I loop and use data structures but still I don't think it should be that high.
Here are the functions mentioned above:
function stake() external nonReentrant whenNotPaused {
        uint _bal = mainNft.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(_bal > 0, "No tokens to stake");
        uint[] memory _tokenIds = getTokenIdsOfOwner(msg.sender);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _tokenIds.length; i++) {
            //check if token exists already in stakers. If it does and owner is different, change to new owner and update timestamp, otherwise skip it. Else push to stakers.
            if (tokenIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]] > 0) {
                Stakers storage stakedToken = stakers[
                    tokenIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]]
                ];
                if (stakedToken.owner != msg.sender) {
                    stakedToken.owner = msg.sender;
                    stakedToken.stakedTime = block.timestamp;
                }
            } else {
                stakers.push(
                    Stakers(msg.sender, _tokenIds[i], block.timestamp)
                );
                tokenIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]] = stakers.length - 1;
            }
        }
        updateLeaderboards(_bal, 0);
        emit Stake(msg.sender);
}

function claimRewards() external nonReentrant whenNotPaused {
        uint _bal = mainNft.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(_bal > 0);
        uint[] memory _tokenIds = getTokenIdsOfOwner(msg.sender);
        uint _len = _tokenIds.length;
        uint _rewards = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
            if (tokenIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]] > 0) {
                Stakers storage stakedToken = stakers[
                    tokenIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]]
                ];
                if (stakedToken.owner == msg.sender) {
                    // get timestamp and calculate rewards
                    uint _stakedAt = stakedToken.stakedTime;
                    _rewards += rewardMath(_stakedAt, msg.sender);
                    // reset timestamp
                    stakedToken.stakedTime = block.timestamp;
                }
            }
        }
        _tokenIds = getFbTokenIdsOfOwner(msg.sender);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _tokenIds.length; i++) {
            if (footballIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]] > 0) {
                Stakers storage stakedToken = fbStakers[
                    footballIdToStakersIndex[_tokenIds[i]]
                ];
                if (stakedToken.owner == msg.sender) {
                    // get timestamp and calculate rewards
                    uint _stakedAt = stakedToken.stakedTime;
                    _rewards += (((rewardRateFB) *
                        (block.timestamp - _stakedAt)) / 1 days);
                    // reset timestamp
                    stakedToken.stakedTime = block.timestamp;
                }
            }
        }

        // get multiplier
        _rewards = (_rewards * (100 + getMultiplier(msg.sender))) / 100;
        // send rewards
        _rewards = sendTokens(_rewards);
        updateLeaderboards(_bal, _rewards);
        emit Claim(msg.sender, _rewards);
        return;
}

Some of the functions used internally:
function getTokenIdsOfOwner(
        address _owner
    ) public view returns (uint[] memory tokensOfOwner) {
        uint256[] memory _tokensOfOwner = mainNft.tokensOfOwner(_owner);
        return _tokensOfOwner;
}

function getMultiplier(address _account) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint _stakingMultiplier = 0;
        uint256 _totalTokensHeld = 0;
        uint256 _len = SM_Contracts.length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
            _totalTokensHeld = walletHoldsToken(
                _account,
                SM_Contracts[i],
                SM_TokenIds[i]
            );
            _stakingMultiplier += SM_Multipliers[i] * _totalTokensHeld;
        }
        if (maxMultiplier == true) {
            if (_stakingMultiplier > maxMultiplierCap) {
                _stakingMultiplier = maxMultiplierCap;
            }
        }
        return _stakingMultiplier;
}

EDIT
So the staking contract is for an NFT collection provided via a minting service provider "HeyMint". I did some debugging and I think the high gas fee is caused from their implementation of tokensOfOwner()
Here is the function
    function tokensOfOwner(address owner) external view virtual override returns (uint256[] memory) {
        unchecked {
            uint256 tokenIdsIdx;
            address currOwnershipAddr;
            uint256 tokenIdsLength = balanceOf(owner);
            uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](tokenIdsLength);
            TokenOwnership memory ownership;
            for (uint256 i = _startTokenId(); tokenIdsIdx != tokenIdsLength; ++i) {
                ownership = _ownershipAt(i);
                if (ownership.burned) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (ownership.addr != address(0)) {
                    currOwnershipAddr = ownership.addr;
                }
                if (currOwnershipAddr == owner) {
                    tokenIds[tokenIdsIdx++] = i;
                }
            }
            return tokenIds;
        }
    }

Anything I can do in this case?

To reduce gas costs, it’s important to consider the efficiency of your code when using for-loops in Solidity. Here are some gas optimization strategies and loop unrolling techniques you can employ:

Use loop unrolling: Instead of using a traditional for-loop, manually repeat the loop body multiple times to reduce the number of iterations.
Minimize storage operations: Avoid unnecessary read and write operations within the loop. Store frequently accessed values outside the loop to reduce gas costs.
Limit loop iterations: If possible, restrict the loop to a fixed number of iterations, avoiding the need for dynamic calculations that may consume more gas.
Use memory variables: Declare and use memory variables instead of storage variables within the loop to reduce gas consumption.

Efficiency in for-loops is crucial for minimizing gas costs. However, it’s also important to be aware of potential array out-of-bounds errors that can occur when using loops in
ANSWER:
For loop for getting stake for some address is bad!
You can use mapping address -> (struct staker,user)
And there store its data.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Mapping {
    struct staker {
        uint256 staked;
        uint256 unstaked;
        // add what you need
    }
    // Mapping from address to uint
    mapping(address => staker) public stakers;

    function get(address _addr) public view returns (staker) {
        // Mapping always returns a staker.
        return stakers[_addr];
    }

    function stake(address _addr) public {
        // Update the value at this address
        staker = get(msg.sender);
        uint256 bal_ = staker.staked;

    }

    function remove(address _addr) public {
        // Reset the value to the default value.
        delete myMap[_addr];
    }
}


How would this solution resolve the for loop I have?
